# mobile ad optimisation for app installs not available

Tags: facebook, mobile, ads

I've set up a new fb app for an IOS app we've launched. When setting up a mobile ad in FB I can't choose the "optimize for app installs" option, only clicks or impressions.
It works fine for another app and can't see any difference in the fb app and ad setup.

I'm guessing the difference must be in the IOS code, but it seems strange the fb app and ad setup would detect that?

So, essentially the question is, what is the reason I can't choose the "optimize for app installs" when creating a mobile app?

Comment: forgot to mention the facebook SDK is installed and we're using it only for tracking app installs.

Comment: Have you misconfigured your app? it should have the ios and/or android details entered